# Ajax in custom module of Drupal

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have one custom module created in drupal having one form.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$form['conditionOrDisease'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Disease Or Condition'),
      '#placeholder' =>  'Disease Or Condition',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    ];
$form['cities'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Cities'),
      '#placeholder'  =>  'Cities',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="col-xxl-2 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>'
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Apply'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::setMessage',
      ],
    ];
    $form['message'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div class="result_message"></div>',
    ];
return $form;
}
public function setMessage(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
$html = '<table class="table table-bordered rounded overflow-hidden search-result">';
    $html .= '<thead class="table-secondary">';
$html .= '<tr>
            <th scope="row">'.$studyFieldObj['Rank'].'</th>
            <td>'.$conditionHtml.'</td>
            <td>'.$interventionHtml.'</td>
            <td>'.$Investigator.'</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>June 6, 2023</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>'.$location.'</td>
            <td>'.$status.'</td>
          </tr>';
    }
          $html .= '</tbody>';
    $html .= '</table>';
    $html .='<ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-sm pagination">
                <li class="page-item prev disabled" data-attrib="previous"><a href="#" class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                <li class="page-item next" data-attrib="next"><a href="#" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
            </ul>';
    $html .= "<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(document).on('click', '#pagination-demo li', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        var pageType = $(this).attr('data-attrib');
    
        // Get the current page number from the pagination wrapper
        var currentPage = parseInt($('#pagination-demo').attr('data-current-page'));
    
        // Update the page number based on the clicked link
        if (pageType === 'previous') {
          currentPage--;
        } else if (pageType === 'next') {
          currentPage++;
        }
    
        // Prepare the data to be sent via AJAX
        var data = {
          currentPage: currentPage,
          pageType: pageType,
          mainCondition: '".$mainCondition."',
          form_id: 'ajax_submit_demo'
        };
    
        // Send the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          data: data,
          url: 'clinical-trial?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax',
          success: function(response) {
            $('.result_message').html(response[1].data);
            // Update the pagination wrapper with the new current page
            $('#pagination-demo').attr('data-current-page', currentPage);
          }
        });
      });
    });</script>";
$response = new AjaxResponse();
      $response->addCommand(
        new HtmlCommand(
          '.result_message',
          $html
        )
      );
    
    return $response;
  }
}
```

In above code on click of Apply button it will return the table consisting of records and previous and next in unorder list.

Now i want to apply ajax on click of previous and next. I have write a code for that as well but it is providing me following error
An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (8 MB) that this server supports.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong. Suggestions appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide the content of your ajax destination file: clinical-trial?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with Ajax and Drupal because, according to your error message, it's a file size problem when uploading.

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (8 MB) that this server supports.

To resolve your problem check the `php.ini` file for setting the file upload size.
And change the following line:

```ini
post_max_size = 25M
upload_max_filesize = 25M
```

Then restart your PHP service. Below is an example of a command to restart PHP if you are using version 7.4 with FPM :

```
service php7.4-fpm restart
```

If you want to know where is the `php.ini` file on your server type this command :

```bash
php --ini
```

This should generate something like that :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File: usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-bcmath.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mysqli.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

Then edit the "Loaded Configuration File".